# split,operate and union dataframe in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

How can we split a dataframe and operate on individual split and union all the individual dataframes results back ?

Lets say i have dataframe with below columns. I need to split the dataframe based on channel and operate on individual splits which adds new column called bucket. then i need to union  back the results.

account,channel,number_of_views

The groupBy is only allowing simple aggreagted operation. On each splitted dataframe i need to do feature extraction.

currently all Feature Transformers of spark-mllib are support only single dataframe.

Comment: Can you show your code? Of course you can make an individual dataframe from a selection of columns from another

Comment: what you want in result

Answer (score -1):

you can randomly split like this

```
val Array(training_data, validat_data, test_data) = raw_data_rating_before_spilt.randomSplit(Array(0.6,0.2,0.2))
```

this will create 3 df then d what you want to do then you can join or union

```
val finalDF = df1.join(df2, df1.col("col_name")===df2.col("col_name"))
```

you can also join multiple df at the same time.
this is what you want or anything else.??

Comment: Thanks For response.  Once i split dataframe how can i run a operation on each splitted dataframe on parallel fashion . I have a function which would add new column to each splitted dataframe .  I dont want to loop on arry and execute it.